# Stuck in while loop for perfect_shuffle_counter for odd length lists but not even length lists

Tags: python-3.x

perfect_shuffle() takes a list and perfectly shuffles it. count_shuffle() counts the number of times a list takes to return to its original state by instantiating perfect_shuffle(). Count_shuffle() works perfectly for even length lists but gets stuck in the while loop for odd length lists. Note that my perfect_shuffle function works for odd length lists by appending a placeholder to the end. Then removing it once shuffled - but don't think this is the issue.

```
def count_shuffle(start):
    """
    Takes list as argument and returns count of the number of perfect 
    shuffles 
    to return to original state

    e.g.
    count_shuffle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    Start:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    1 :  [1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10]
    2 :  [1, 8, 6, 4, 2, 9, 7, 5, 3, 10]
    3 :  [1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10]
    4 :  [1, 5, 9, 4, 8, 3, 7, 2, 6, 10]
    5 :  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    6 :  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Out[172]: 6

    """
    print('Start: ',start)
    current = perfect_shuffle(start)
    count = 1

    while current != start:
        print(count,': ',current)
        current = perfect_shuffle(current)
        count+=1
    print(count,': ',current)
    return count


def perfect_shuffle(a_list):
    """
    Takes a sequence as argument and returns the 'perfect shuffle' of 
    that list

    Eg. 
    In[1]: perfect_shuffle([1,2,3,4,5])
    Out[1]: [1,4,2,5,3]

    """
    perfect_list = []

    #if list length is odd, append placeholder '0' to make even (to remove later)    
    if len(a_list)%2==1:
        odd = 1
        a_list.append(0)
    else:
        odd = 0  

    # half of list length      
    half = len(a_list)//2

    a = zip(a_list[:half],a_list[half:])

    # Flattens a from list of sublists to single list
    for i in a:
        for k in i:
            perfect_list.append(k)

    # If input list length len(a_list) is odd then this removes the placeholder  at the end
    if odd:
        perfect_list = perfect_list[:-1]

    return perfect_list
```

Comment: what is the actual output you get ?? Your `while current != start:` loop currently outputs the value for each count greater than 1 twice (your example does not show this).

Comment: @casualcoder sorry the second print was not supposed to be in the while loop (it was tabbed when I pasted the code but I've fixed it now). The primary output is the count, thus the 'return count' part. The print statements were more for debugging and display purposes.

Comment: @casualcoder it's not 'randomly' removing the last element. For a perfect shuffle of an odd length list the last element will always be the placeholder so it is perfectly fine to remove it each time - maybe try runnning the code.

Comment: you are correct I misread/misinterpreted what your shuffle was doing, running the code hepled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to copy `a_list` inside `perfect_shuffle`, and only alter the copy. E.g. change the part before the for-loop to:

```
perfect_list = []
b_list = a_list[:]
print(id(a_list))
#if list length is odd, append placeholder '0' to make even (to remove later)    
if len(a_list)%2==1:
    odd = 1
    b_list.append(0)
else:
    odd = 0  

# half of list length      
half = len(b_list)//2

a = zip(b_list[:half],b_list[half:])
```

Right now, you're changing the start-list by appending 0 to it, but the current will have dropped the 0, so they will never be the same. 
Output when printing current and start within your `count_shuffle`:

```
Start:  [1, 2, 3]
1 :  [1, 3, 2] [1, 2, 3, 0]
2 :  [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 0]
3 :  [1, 3, 2] [1, 2, 3, 0]
```

ad infinitum.

By calling `perfect_shuffle(start)`, you are only providing a pointer to `start`, which will then be altered. You are not copying the list.

Comment: Ah thanks guys.. this was doing my head in as my perfect_shuffle() function seemed to be working fine - but that makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the issue, if you print out your start and current values in the while loop you will notice that your start value has a 0 appended to it. I believe that this is happening as in your perfect shuffle function you append a 0 to your a_list itself and not a placeholder for the list. This mutates your initial list to now have an extra 0 (only if had an odd length initially). You can get around this by using a placeholder for a_list and append the 0 to the placeholder instead.